# Retain config files during upgrade

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, packaging, debian

I'm trying to package up my application into a .deb file and it works. However; upon upgrading my old config files get overwritten.

Based on the [following diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLSTc.png), I was thinking about doing some trickery with pre/postinst and pre/postrem. Moving files into a temporary location and moving them back later on in the upgrade process.

I would like to know if there is something built into apt that would take care of this for me, instead of writing something that works, but makes it difficult to maintain in the future.

Comment: During, say, a release-upgrade, do you want users to be able to select between the old config, the new config, and/or migrate customization they have done?

Comment: No, just keep their old config files automatically

Comment: See https://wiki.debian.org/PackageConfigUpgrade

Comment: I don't see the need for much trickery under the conditions you have set: During postinst, test for the existence of the config file. If it's there, do nothing. If it's not there, install one.

Comment: @Panther, config changes are properly done during postinst, and cme (and others) permit testing/replacement. My intent was to explain one method that is explicitly allowed by debian. My apologies for being unclear.

Comment: So does that mean that the config files would not be part of the .deb file, but I'd create them after install? Maybe a default config file should be part of the .deb and then I could copy that where the actual config file would go?